# Why does perl translate a tick into a colon?

Tags: perl

Given this program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $zx_size = 32;
my $x = "$zx_size'h0";
```

Perl tells me this:

```
Name "zx_size::h0" used only once: possible typo at concat.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $zx_size::h0 in string at concat.pl line 7.
```

Why?

It appears there are multiple ways to specify the namespace of a var. Are there others?

Is it possible to turn off this behavior?

Comment: try this "$zx_size\'h0" (with backslash) or "$zx_size 'h0"; (with blankspace). Essentially you have to separate the variable and the content of the string. Perl thinks that zxsize'h0 is the name of the variable. Alternatively you can try "$zx_size" . "'h0" as well. All the best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl string, a variable in a string followed by a single quote and another character does what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360205/perl-string-a-variable-in-a-string-followed-by-a-single-quote-and-another-chara)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The old package delimiter was a single quote `'` which was originally used to ease transition to Perl for Ada programmers. It was replaced with `::` to be more readable and ease the transition of C++ programmers.

It is still supported for backwards compatibility, but you can wrap your scalar in `{..}` to have it interpolate correctly.

```
my $x = "${zx_size}'h0";
```

or

```
my $x = "$zx_size\'h0";
```

Comment: Or `my $x = $zx_size . "'h0";`

Comment: weird. the answer was posted 21 hrs ago but the above comment was made 20 hrs ago? BUG!

Comment: @Hunter Thank you for the Ada background. Interesting.

Answer (score 11):

The single quote character `'` was used by earlier Perls to denote package scope in the same way as `::`, and it is still supported for backwards compatibility.

To do what you want, you'll need to use the `${}` syntax to tell Perl where the identifier ends and the literal begins:

```
"${zx_size}'h0"
```

Note that this is the same thing you would have to do if you wanted to the value of `$zx_size` followed by any other literal character that is legal to appear in an identifier:

```
"${zx_size}foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

Read [perlmod](http://p3rl.org/perlmod). The very second paragraph. And no, there's no way to turn it off, at least for now. Theoretically, someone could write a `no feature` pragma for it, but it's been that way for 20 years without causing too many problems...