# Perl string, a variable in a string followed by a single quote and another character does what?

Tags: string, perl

I just encountered my first odd "quirk" of Perl in a long time.  I can't seem to find any documentation of it online and I don't know what Perl is doing.

Let's just cut to the chase:

```
my $name = "Steve";
my $v = "$name's name is $name";
```

The value of $v would turn out to be " name is Steve".  I use vim and the first $name turns an odd color (green instead of the normal teal).  So I know this is a known feature, but I don't understand what is happening.

For those who might want to suggest alternatives, I know I can do either of the following without any problems:

```
$v = $name . "'s name is $name";
$v = "${name}'s name is $name";
```

I just am curious as to what Perl is doing in the first case I gave and what its uses are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does perl translate a tick into a colon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411126/why-does-perl-translate-a-tick-into-a-colon)

Comment: This is a clearer question and answer than the mentioned "duplicate". I'd rather have this question open to reference than the other.

Comment: @ikegami Close the other one, then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html),

> The old package delimiter was a single quote, but double colon is now
>   the preferred delimiter, in part because it's more readable to humans,
>   and in part because it's more readable to emacs macros. It also makes
>   C++ programmers feel like they know what's going on--as opposed to
>   using the single quote as separator, which was there to make Ada
>   programmers feel like they knew what was going on. Because the
>   old-fashioned syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility,
>   if you try to use a string like `"This is $owner's house"`, you'll be
>   accessing `$owner::s`; that is, the $s variable in package `owner`,
>   which is probably not what you meant. Use braces to disambiguate, as
>   in `"This is ${owner}'s house"`.

You could also use `"This is $owner\'s house"`.